# python subprocess avoid signal handling by the child

Tags: python, signals, subprocess, signal-handling

well, I have a usr1 signal handler in a script. By sending a SIGUSR1 from outside to my script, my handler does its work, but the signal is spread also to the child that I create via Popen. How can I do this?

Comment: Signals don't "spread" by default; you're relaying it yourself.

Comment: @phihag nope, I simply make a subprocess.Popen in a script X. Then I'm sending a SIGUSR1 from outside and I'm catching it in my script. At the time my inner script cries because of sending him SIGUSR1 that I've never addressed to him.

Comment: @Method [Here is a demo](https://gist.github.com/3820337) that on my system outputs `parent: SIGUSR1 caught` (+ the PIDs). Can you reproduce that behavior? If not, what Python interpreter are you using, and on what OS? If so, how does your script differ from the demo script?

Comment: @phihag my case is a quite different from your exemple, thank you for it. In my script I use subprocess.Popen(), but not subprocess.call(), anyway it should not change the fork behaviour. In my script I Popen the rsync program. After sending my signal, my handler says "Got it", but rsync is exiting with error code 20, which means that it has caught the sigusr1 signal.

Comment: @Method `subprocess.call` is just an interface for `subprocess.Popen`.   No offense, but it is [extremely unlikely](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/10/10127054.aspx) that there is some kind of fundamental breakdown of your OS kernel that would cause a signal to "spread". Can you reduce the problem to [a reproducible example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @phihag I agree for the similarity of popen as call and I've mentioned.

Comment: I think that I've found my problem. By coincidence rsync is pretending to recieve sigusr1 if killing it (what I do somewhere in my script by kill -15). So that has nothing to do with my sigusr1 sending from outside.

Answer (score 0):

The `rsync` [manual page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/rsync.1.php) says that exit code 20 means:

```
Received SIGUSR1 or SIGINT
```

So if you are killing it with `kill` (not `kill -15` which you say you sometimes use) then it would die with this exit code too.